# How to avoid the "Z" in my PostgreSQL datetime

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, datetime

I am using the material-UI to select a date and store it in a SQL Database.  When I send the date to the DB it is in this format "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM" for example "2017-05-24T10:30".  However when I fetch the dates from the DB they come out like this "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000Z" for example "2019-06-14T10:30:00.000Z"

Now I am using a calendar package called FullCalendar, which interprets the "Z" as -5H.  So all of the dates on my calendar are moved back 5H.  The really bazaar thing is that this only happens when the app is deployed on Heroku.  If I run the app locally and try to fetch the dates the database is automatically adding 5H to the times to compensate for the "Z" and the dates are displayed correctly on the calendar.

I'm looking for a solution to either get rid of the "Z" or make the heroku and local app deployments consistent.

I'm not sure if there is any relevant code to include here.  The POST and GET methods to the DB are pretty standard.  Let me know if I can add anything that might be of use.

Comment: What is the definition of your column?  Is it timestamp with or without time zone?

Comment: Also, what is the `DateStyle` setting on the database?

Comment: I'm not sure about DateStyle but the column is TIMESTAMP,

Comment: If it's possible to use timestamptz (timestamp with time zone), you will almost certainly find that it behaves in less surprising ways.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I will look into that!

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` = timestamp without time zone. You won't get a "Z" at the end on a `TIMESTAMP` type. Therefore something between the table and the point where you are accessing it is casting/converting the type, or it's not really being stored as a `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: @404 you're correct.  It appears that the data in the DB is formatted as "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" without the "T" or "Z".  But as soon as I retrieve the data it is formatted differently.  Would PostgreSQL be doing some kind of auto formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, this will be the easy solution (not the best):

```
SELECT LEFT(cast('2019-06-14T10:30:00.000Z' AS varchar),16)
```

Result: "2019-06-14T10:30"

Look at these functions for better answers in terms of performance: AT TIME ZONE, date_trunc

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html

Comment: It actually appears like the data in the DB doesn't have the "Z"  somehow the format is getting automatically changed when I perform a SELECT on the DB.

Comment: Look at what time zone your server is, then add the time zone to the variable, should be correct. have a look here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html